# Accessing list of list of lists

Tags: tcl

Having

```
set x {{{a b} {c d}}}
```

I would like to read "a".
Is there a cleaner way than:

```
lindex [lindex [lindex $x 0] 0] 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lindex` command supports two other ways of doing that access:

1. Multiple keys:

   ```
   lindex $x 0 0 0
   ```
2. Compound keys:

   ```
   lindex $x {0 0 0}
   ```

You can't mix the two in the same call; compound keys only work if they're the sole index argument. Just to keep a little bit of comprehensibility, both for people using the command and people implementing it.

The `lset` command supports the same indexing schemes.

Comment: If your `lindex` doesn't support this, you're using a very old version of Tcl (pre-8.4) and can put up with the consequences of that (or upgrade).